# Malloc and memcpy to copy data using an offset

Tags: c++, malloc, memcpy

I have a curl callback that contains a some header info and then a jpeg image.

I want to copy out the jpeg image from this data and save it to a file.
I have never used malloc or memcpy before but I have did the following:

```
//data = the data that curl has returned
//datalength = the length of the data that curl has returned
//startpos = the starting position of the jpeg image in data
//the length of the jpeg image

//example data
//datalength=13209
//startpos = 62
//imagelangth=13127
bool SaveImage( void* data, size_t datalength, int startpos, int imageLength)
{
    //1. Allocate a buffer to store the jpeg image
    BYTE* image = (BYTE*)malloc(sizeof(BYTE)*imageLength);
    if( image != nullptr)
    {
        //2. Copy out the image info to the buffer
        BYTE* imageStartPos = (BYTE*)data + startpos;
        memcpy( image, imageStartPos, imageLength);

        //3. Save the image to file
        FILE* pFile;
        fopen_s(&pFile, "image.jpeg", "w");
        if(pFile != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(image,sizeof(BYTE), imageLength, pFile);
            fclose(pFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that I get a jpeg image created that is about 13k in size but I cannot open it in ms paint as it says its corrupt.  I assume that I have made a mistake in my pointer calculations above.

Any ideas anyone as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using C library calls in C++ code ? You do know that there are much better alternatives in C++ I hope ?

Comment: You have a memory leak, you never free the allocated memory.

Comment: Any possibilities that the image data is actually encoded in the received data?

Comment: Try setting the `fopen_s` open mode to "wb" rather than "w" so that it doesn't do newline translations. Alternatively use `open`

Comment: I'm not sure if the image is encoded or not yet. I have changed it to wb but still the same problem.  Thanks for quick response.

Comment: startpos + imagelength != datalength ?

Comment: Look at what you wrote in a hex editor and compare it to what a correct jpeg file looks like.  Hard to say if your calculations are incorrect or not since we can't duplicate the issue.

Comment: I opened my jpeg file and deleted 2 blank lines from the top of it and I now can open my jpeg image and view it. I have failed to parse these 2 blank lines in a previous function which I will now fix.  Thanks :)

Comment: @HarryBoy - I suspect the two blank are due to you not opening the file in binary mode